# Gradle project sync failed-Android studio

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am new to `android studio` gradle project.I imported an existing project to the `android studio`.When I tried to build, it showing error as `Gradle project sync failed`.

How to solve that error? And I have v2.1.3 of the android studio using Gradle 2.4.

**Error message is:**

```
  Error:Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0.
  Searched in the following locations:
  file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android 
  Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/1.1.0/gradle-
  1.1.0.pom
  file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android 
  Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/1.1.0/gradle-
  1.1.0.jar
  http://repo1.maven.org/com/android/tools/build/gradle/1.1.0/gradle-
  1.1.0.pom
  http://repo1.maven.org/com/android/tools/build/gradle/1.1.0/gradle-
  1.1.0.jar
  Required by:
  :android_upgrade:unspecified
```

**Build.gradle:**

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org' }
}
if (gradle.gradleVersion >= "2.2") {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
    }
} else if (gradle.gradleVersion >= "2.1") {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0+'
    }
} else {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0+'
    }
}
}
```

Comment: create new android project from your android studio, check all versions in app and project level gradle files, after you will get full information

Comment: Post your build.gradle files

Comment: Is your error resolved?

Comment: @nimi0112 Not yet resolved

Comment: @srinu Thank you.I will try.

Comment: @KarthikaKavi Update your Android Studio the latest version is 3.0.1 and it will fix your gradle issues

Answer (score 1):

The first solution is to update to the latest android studio version 3.0.1 [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html), update the Gradle plugin to the latest by navigating to Help-> check for update-> [download updates].

If you are not excited about updating to updated tools, kindly share your build.gradle file here and I can help further. Android is awesome just get your tools working.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

change classpath in dependencies :

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
}
```

else update gradle :

```
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
```

this will works :

Comment: To use the plugin v3.x you also need to use Gradle v4.x